# NSURLConnectionLoader exception on first HTTPS request

Tags: macos, exception, https, nsurlconnection, osx-mountain-lion

I have an IOS App that sends HTTPS request to a server, using NSURLConnection, it works without any issue.

Now, I'm trying to put this App on OSX and to reuse code from the IOS App. It's the first time I'm developing on OSX, so I'm a beginner ;-)

My OSX get an exception when I'm sending my first HTTPS requests (using Post), the exception is about NSURLConnectionLoader (it ends at libc++abi.dylib __cxa throw and it seems it has been raised due to security issue Security::KeyChainCore...).

Next, on the debugger, if I click many times on continue, the request is successfully sent and I'm get the correct answer from the server.

The following requests that are sent are working fine (no exceptions), only the first one has issues.

Any idea? Any differences between OSX and IOS for NSURLConnection?
Thanks for the help,

Sebastien.